# How to reverse capitalization of specific alphabetical characters in a string (case insensitive), leaving all other chars in the string unaffected?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am trying to implement a function that searches a given string and reverses capitalization of all occurrences of particular alphabetical characters (case insensitive), leaving numbers, special characters, and other alphabetical characters unaffected.

For example, if theString = "abc123XYZ" and reverseCaps= "cyz", the result should be "abC123Xyz".

I have tried various implementations and fixes, but cannot get it to work properly. The result I am getting now is "ABC123xyz".

Here is my code:

```
public static String flipCaseChars(String theString, String reverseCap) {

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(theString.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < theString.length(); i++) {

        char c = theString.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            buf.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
        }

        else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
            buf.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
        }

        // if char is neither upper nor lower
        else {
            buf.append(c);
        }
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

What should I do? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I missing something here? I see that some answers here are getting voted up but they're not doing what the OP has requested. According to the example input (**"abc123XYZ"**) and output (**"abC123Xyz"**), I see it that the letter-case of the characters within the **reverseCaps** string variable is irrelevant. They could have been any letter-case but, if any one of them are encountered within the input string (**theString**) regardless of current letter-case state any one of the supplied characters letter-case if flipped to its' opposing state.

So if the Input String was: **ab-c-123-C-XYz** and the **reverseCaps** variable contained **"cyz"** then the output should be: **ab-C-123-c-XyZ**. Am I mistaken?

If I'm not mistaken then the following code will carry out the task explained above:

```
public static String flipCaseCharacters(String inputString, String charactersToFlip) {
    StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
    for (char inChar : inputString.toCharArray()) {
        for (char ctFlip : charactersToFlip.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.toUpperCase(inChar) == Character.toUpperCase(ctFlip)) {
                inChar = Character.isUpperCase(inChar) ? 
                         Character.toLowerCase(inChar) : 
                         Character.toUpperCase(inChar);
                break;
            }
        }
        newString.append(inChar);
    }
    return newString.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String flipCaseChars(String theString, String reverseCap) {

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(theString.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < theString.length(); i++) {
        char c = theString.charAt(i);
        if (reverseCap.indexOf(c) >= 0){
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                buf.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
            }   else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                buf.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
            } else { 
                buf.append(c);
            }
        } else {
            buf.append(c);
        }
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat, it is indeed needed as the function returns buf.

Comment: Sorry - my bad.

Comment: Thank you. This almost works. The result I am getting now is "abC123XYZ". It looks like it is not reversing capitalization on the Y or Z because the input for reverseCap is all lowercase. If I change the input to reverseCap = "cYZ", then it works properly. How can this code be modified so that the letters to reverse are case insensitive?

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to loop through the reverseCap String and do a conditional replace

```
for (char c : reverseCap.toCharArray()) {

    if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
        theString = theString.replace(c, Character.toUpperCase(c));
    }
    else {
        theString = theString.replace(c, Character.toLowerCase(c));
    }

}

return theString;
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to check if the character is upper or lower case.  It just flips case of the character as appropriate.  This presumes that the reverse list of characters is all lowercase, as shown in the example.

It works by checking and then manipulating the bit `0x20`that determines upper and lower case in ASCII characters.

The `^` is the exclusive OR operator that flips to the opposite case by flipping the case bit.

```java
   public static String flipCaseChars(String theString, String reverseCap) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (char c : theString.toCharArray()) {
         // is the character in the list?
         if (reverseCap.indexOf(c | 0x20) >= 0) {
            c ^= 0x20; // flip the case
         }
         sb.append(c);
      }
      return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I basically made a `HashSet<Character>` of `reverseCap` and then the rest follows [@toootooo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58740767/6601614)
Here it is:

```
static String flipCaseChars(String theString, String reverseCap) {
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(theString.length());
    HashSet<Character> collect = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < reverseCap.length(); i++) {
        collect.add(Character.toLowerCase(reverseCap.charAt(i)));
        collect.add(Character.toUpperCase(reverseCap.charAt(i)));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < theString.length(); i++) {
        char currentChar = theString.charAt(i);
        if (collect.contains(currentChar)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(currentChar)) {
                currentChar = Character.toLowerCase(currentChar);
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(currentChar)){
                currentChar = Character.toUpperCase(currentChar);
            }
        }
        stringBuilder.append(currentChar);
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

The only advantage of this approach is that the lookup of the characters in `reverseCap` is done in constant time and the time complexity is directly propertional to the length of `theString`.